# Why does the whole application close when AllocConsole is closed? is there any way to change this?

Tags: c#

I needed to use console inside c# form application. I found AllocConsole while researching. My commands are working, but when I'm done in the console, I want to return to my form application, but when I close the console, the whole application closes.

I can't access my form application even if I want to leave it running in the background without closing the console, but my form application it's getting frozen

how can I solve this?

My Codes

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

    public Doxy0()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AllocConsole();
a=lblbox1.Text;
int milliseconds = 2000;
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Activation Started", Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green);
Console.WriteLine("Activation Completed" + a, Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `AllocConsole` will create and **attach** a new console to the process that is calling *AllocConsole*. Hence, when closing the console window, the process is also being closed. Thus, if your program is finished with the console stuff, [detach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) the allocated console again from your program.